# Could this diagram illustrate the relations between R5RS Scheme primitive data types?

Tags: types, scheme

I am trying to draw a diagram to illstrate the relations between R5RS Scheme primitive data types, so that I can

- a) remind myself, when I try to rule out some special cases.
- b) share with others, if they are interested.

but **I'm not sure whether there are any misunderstandings / non-standard terms**, or if there are better diagrams online to illustrate the same idea...

[image: r5rs scheme datatypes]

Thanks for your help.

---

After taking @ChrisJester-Young 's advice, I have redraw the diagram, hope this time I'm getting close to it. :)

[image: r5rs scheme datatypes(rev1)]

---

Revision 2

[image: r5rs scheme datatypes(rev2)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be less confusing if you used *external representation* instead of *code snippet*. Then you can do away with all the quoting.

Basically, the external representation of a dotted pair is `(foo . bar)`, where `foo` is in the car slot and `bar` is in the cdr slot of the pair.

On top of that, you have lists. There are three kinds of lists: proper, improper, and circular.

A proper list is either:

- The empty-list or end-of-list special object, `()`, or
- A dotted pair with the cdr slot set to another proper list.

Example: `(1 2 3 4)` (which is the same as `(1 2 3 4 . ())`)

An improper list is either:

- An object that is neither a dotted pair nor the empty-list `()` object, or
- A dotted pair with the cdr slot set to another improper list.

Example: `(1 2 3 . 4)`

A circular list is:

- A dotted pair where, when chasing down the successive cdrs, you never ever reach a non-dotted-pair object.

Examples: `#0=(1 2 3 4 . #0#)`, `(1 2 . #1=(3 4 . #1#))`

Comment: I can understand using “external representation” instead of “code snippet”, it has fewer variations and let me focus on output.

Comment: As to "improper list", your definition seems to imply that atomic data type like **symbol, number or string** can be classified into **improper list** category, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Till now I haven't read about or used any circular list... Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: After a little further research, I finally know how to create a circular list. You are right, "code snippet" could make it unreadable. But I may supplement the code snippets as diagram footnotes, just like diagram legend.

Comment: Yes, atoms (other than the empty list) are indeed a base case for improper lists. You can create circular lists using either [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)'s `circular-list` function, or [SRFI 38](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-38/srfi-38.html)'s `read-with-shared-structure`.

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing the "base case" idea, I should change my thinking model, and then modify the diagram substantially to reflect this...

Comment: @ChrisJesterYoung, would you have a look at the revised version and give further comments?

Comment: Almost! In the green box, you should say "dotted pair whose cdr is a proper list".

Comment: Oh... no, I was misled by my own **non-typical proper list sample** `(a b . ())`, now I know why diagram are sometimes not the best way to convey subtle ideas. Even if we both agree on the diagram group titles, it may still be misleading when list samples are non-typical... and who knows if there are other mind-traps? :P